# How to I exclude/ignore classes/packages from being instrumented by the maven-emma plugin?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am working on java/spring/hibernate/Maven based project. I have some unit tests and I have configured emma pulign for code coverage report.
I have added "emma-maven-plugin" to generate code coverage report in POM.xml file.

```
<!-- Emma profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>EMMA</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <finalName>BuildForEmma</finalName>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <inherited>true</inherited>
                            <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                            <reportFormat>xml</reportFormat>
                            <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-classes/emma/classes</classesDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>emma</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

When I run command like "mvn clean install emma:emma". Code coverage emma report genreated successfully. But in code coverage report there are many classes and packages which not covered via my test case so I need to exclude and ignores those packages/classes to improve code coverage results.

For this I tried and add this entry in emma puling.

```
<instrumentation>
<ignores>
<ignore>com.exam.generated.ceq.*</ignore>
<ignore>com.exam.activities.*</ignore>
<ignore>com.exam.activities.cdr.generated.*</ignore>
<ignore>com.exam.admin.*</ignore>
</ignores>
</instrumentation>
```

But it not works, I have also checked many regarding link but not able to get success. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the exclusion list in the plugin's configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
    <configuration>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        <reportFormat>xml</reportFormat>
        <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-classes/emma/classes</classesDirectory>
        <!-- Exclusion configuration -->
        <filters>
            <filter>                                     
                <excludes>**/com.exam.generated.ceq.**</excludes>
                <excludes>**/com.exam.activities.**</excludes>
                <excludes>**/com.exam.activities.cdr.generated.**</excludes>
                <excludes>**/com.exam.admin.**</excludes>
            </filter>
         </filters>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>emma</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Mureinik I need more help from your side. Do you have any link which define the directory path? Actually I am facing issue with making pattern.<excludes>${project.build.directory}/generated-classes/emma/classes/com/exam/test/generated/vits/*.class</excludes>

Comment: @Dani how about `<excludes>**/generated-classes/**</excludes>` ?

Comment: Mureinik, I checked with <excludes>**/generated-classes/**</excludes> but I am still getting all classes in emma code coverage report. With above changes I am not able to excludes any file.